# Hibernate "mappedBy" use

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have read several examples about creating associations between tables with Hibernate and I have got a little bit confused. I want initilaly to know how many tables will be created in the database without specifying any annotation on the other side as with the code:

```
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="COMP_ID")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    ...
}
```

I suspect two tables Flight, Company and the Flight contains a foreign key Company_Id. AM I right? What is the difference if I add the "mappedBy" on the other side as:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
    public Set<Flight> getFlights() {
        ...
    }
}
```

How many tables will be created by the second approach? I suppose the second approach establishes a bidirectional association. What is practical difference between the two cases? What is going on also with the "mappedBy" annotation in the @ManyToMany association?

Comment: You're asking what the difference is between the two cases, but you only present one case. What is the other case? Also, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119531/hibernate-jpa-manytoone-vs-onetomany/16119715#16119715

Comment: The first case is without any annotation in the Company Entity and the second is with the annotation @OneToMany(mappedBy="company") as you see in the second code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't put any annotation on the flights property, the default mapping would apply, which is `@Basic`. That means that the whole contents of the list would be serialized and stored in a column named flights.

This is obviously not what you want. What you want is to make it the inverse side of the ManyToOne association defined in Flight. That's what `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")` does.

Other than that, your assumption is correct. A ManyToOne is mapped by default using a join column in the table of the entity. Using the JoinColumn annotation allows specifying a name other than the default one for the join column (as well as other properties of this join column).

Comment: What do you mean by "whole contents of the list would be serialized and stored in a column named flights"? How is that depicted in the database? In order to understand I need the explanation about what is going on in the database. I would like also the same explanation for "the inverse side of the ManyToOne association defined in Flight".

Comment: I mean that Java serialization would be used to transform the whole contents of the list to a byte array, and this byte array would be stored in a column named `flights` in the company table. Being the inverse side of the ManyToOne means that the two fields are actually the same association : a company C1 has the flights F1, F2, and F3, because F1, F2 and F3 have C1 as their company. A single join column in the Flight table is needed to map this bidirectional association.

Answer (score 1):

When your are using bidirectional relationship there is a change to store relationship in both tables by using mappedby you can avoid it. From your example if you remove mappedby, flight and company both tables will have relationship field.