# JPA 2.0 (Hibernate) generates incorrect join table PK for @OneToMany with @JoinTable

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I've using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.3.5 and trying to use Hibernate to auto generate my tables.

I've created the following entry in my Contact entity:

```
/**
 * Address
 */
@Valid
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "contact_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@OrderColumn
private List<Address> addresses;
```

Hibernate is properly creating the contact table, but the join table is created without the correct PK:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_address` (
  `contact_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `addresses_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_mvvtppjfu6d0lcjm83u5youn8` (`address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4fntyt0q2l6vkfg7t38pg4i94` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contact` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_mvvtppjfu6d0lcjm83u5youn8` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The PK listed here is only the `contact_id`, which is incorrect.  That will not allow me to have multiple addresses assigned.  Rather, the PK should be a composite PK of `contact_id`, `address_id`.

Is Hibernate at fault, or is there something wrong in my JPA annotation?  This is a one-way association.

As noted by a couple of people, technically speaking, I don't need a join table for a @OneToMany, but given that I need to use the Address entity in other entity objects, it is cleaner for me to use join tables for all the associations.

I have managed to hack around a solution using the @ManyToMany association and specifying a unique constraint on the join columns, but I am trying to understand if there is something wrong with my JPA or if it is a Hibernate bug.

Comment: Why do you need a JoinTable for a OneToMany relationship? ManyToMany requires a JoinTable as far as I know.

Comment: I didn't specify it in my question, but I need to use the Address object in several different entities.  Consequently, it is cleaner for me to use a join table here, even if it is only a OneToMany.

Comment: I think the problem is nicely commented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many

\@OneToMany means, that you can assign multiple addresses to your contact, but the same address can not be assigned to more contacts. Therefore the unique constraint across the address_id and not address_id + contact_id. That is why \@ManyToMany works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need One To Many relationship between Contact and Address where one contact has many addresses. Following will suffice without an associative table.

```
@Valid
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

Comment: Although that technically does work, it doesn't fix my join table. :)  I need/want to use a JoinTable even though it is a OneToMany as I need to use the Address entity in other entities, and it is a cleaner solution architecturally to use a join table in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more details to your question. For example, how have you annotated the `Address` entity?

Anyway, if you annotate and define your entities correctly, Hibernate will generate the tables correctly for you:

```java
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private String id;

    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "contact_addresses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "contact_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "address_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String brand) {
        this.fullName = brand;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> contacts) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        getAddresses().add(address);
        address.setContact(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private String id;

    private String streetAddress;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contact contact;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String name) {
        this.streetAddress = name;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample test case:

```
@Test
public void testContactAddresses() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ContactAddresses");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setFullName("Steve Ballmer");

    Address address1 = new Address();
    address1.setStreetAddress("Developers Street");

    Address address2 = new Address();
    address2.setStreetAddress("Developers Developers Street");

    Address address3 = new Address();
    address3.setStreetAddress("Developers Developers Developers Street");

    contact.addAddress(address1);
    contact.addAddress(address2);
    contact.addAddress(address3);

    entityManager.persist(contact);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

And here are the DDL statements executed by Hibernate:

```sql
Hibernate: drop table Address if exists
Hibernate: drop table Contact if exists
Hibernate: drop table contact_addresses if exists
Hibernate: create table Address (id varchar(255) not null, streetAddress varchar(255), contact_id varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Contact (id varchar(255) not null, fullName varchar(255), primary key (id))

Hibernate: create table contact_addresses (
    contact_id varchar(255) not null, 
    address_id varchar(255) not null, 
    primary key (contact_id, address_id)
)

Hibernate: alter table contact_addresses add constraint UK_mxmb2y0iu8624h4rrdamayobp unique (address_id)
Hibernate: alter table Address add constraint FK98iji1i9ycae5a36rman0vd17 foreign key (contact_id) references Contact
Hibernate: alter table contact_addresses add constraint FK6n27pwv86i3cx03jv3i9taidw foreign key (address_id) references Address
Hibernate: alter table contact_addresses add constraint FKmw2sdpyxrxj3obg1x1ltdlwbo foreign key (contact_id) references Contact
```