# having problem determine the relationship between tables (Many-to-many OR one-to-one)

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, express, relational-database

need help, I have two tables (member, event) every member has many different events, and every event has many different members as attendees. Would this be many to many relationship or one to one relationship?

Comment: *many* different events ...*many* different attendees .... why should this be one to one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference Between One-to-Many, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many)

Comment: And what do you expect, from what you have read in your references about those terms or about database design, including google hits from [so]? [ask] This is an obvious & obviously easily found faq. Please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a many-to-many relationship.
This is because:

1 member can attend **many** events; and
1 event can be attended by **many** members.

You will need something like a `map` table to maintain the relationship between the two tables