# Querying a database with a one to many relationship

Tags: php, sql

I am making a database that when users register, they pick 3 games they would like to play. the games are stored in a separate table (gameinfo) from the user information table (personalinformation). I am querying with the first game being shown but I would like all three shown for each user. How would I implement showing all the games?

I have tried to create different variables for each game, but that has seemed to not work as I expected and broke. the games when they are stored on the personalinformation table are stored as numbers like 1 or 2. these are linked to the gameinfo table and are the primary key for each game.

**Structure of database** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtoDU.jpg

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'esportclub');
    $sql = "SELECT user_ID, username, Email, Gender, firstName, lastName, gameName FROM personalinformation, gameinfo WHERE game_id = firstGame";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      echo "<table>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo " <tr><td> Name: ". $row{"username"}. " </td><td> Email: ". $row{"Email"}.  " </td><td> Gender: ". $row{"Gender"}. "</td>" .
          "<td> First Name: ". $row{"firstName"}. " </td><td> First Game: ". $row{"gameName"}. "</td><td> Last Name: ". $row{"lastName"}. "</td>" . "</td></tr>" ;
      }
      echo "</table>";
    } 
    else{
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Can we see your database structure? This seems like a ["many-to-many` relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3113938/924299). I'd use a reference table to associate users and games by storing pairs of `user_ID` and `game_id`. Then [`JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) the tables together accordingly.

Comment: I have added a link to an imgur post with the screenshots of my database. I have also realised that the relationship is a many to many relationship.

Comment: You would need to join on FirstGame, SecondGame, and ThirdGame in order to get all 3. Another option would be to put the User_ID in the gameinfo table and join on User_ID, or do something like what @showdev said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would create a table to associate users and games by storing unique pairs of `user_ID` and `game_id` values. Then I'd JOIN the tables together accordingly.

However, I see that you are storing three game values for each user in the `personalinformation` table, in columns named `firstGame`,`secondGame`, and `thirdGame`.

In that case, you can JOIN the game table to each of those columns.
So, with your existing structure:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    game1.`gameName` as `firstGame_name`,
    game2.`gameName` as `secondGame_name`,
    game3.`gameName` as `thirdGame_name`
FROM `personalinformation` p
LEFT JOIN `games` as game1 ON (game1.`game_id` = p.`firstGame`)
LEFT JOIN `games` as game2 ON (game2.`game_id` = p.`secondGame`)
LEFT JOIN `games` as game3 ON (game3.`game_id` = p.`thirdGame`)
WHERE 1; // or WHERE p.`user_ID` = :user_ID;
```

---

### EDIT

Since many users can own a game and a user can own many games, it sounds like a "many-to-many" relationship.

Here is my preferred method for that type of relationship. One advantage is that you don't need to limit the number of assigned games. That is, a user can own any number of games.

Create a third table to store unique user/game pairs.
It will tells you which games are assigned to which users.
Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_game` (
  `user_id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
  `game_id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE `user_game`
  ADD UNIQUE `unique pair` (`user_id`, `game_id`);
```

Then join the three tables together:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    g.`game_id`,
    g.`gameName`
FROM `personalinformation` u
LEFT JOIN `user_game` as ug ON ( ug.`user_id` = u.`user_ID` )
LEFT JOIN `games` as g ON ( g.`game_id` = ug.`game_id` )
WHERE 1;
```

You'll get back one row for every user/game relationship.
If one user has three games, that user will have three rows in the result, each row including one `gameName`.

For example:

```
Name   Game
----   -----------------
Jane   League of Legends
Jane   Minecraft
Fred   Dota 2
Alex   Minecraft
Alex   War Dragons
Alex   Fortnite
```

---

More complex display might require some processing:

```
<?php

$users = array();

while($row= mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

    $uid = $row->user_ID;

    // if this user isn't in the array...
    if (!array_key_exists($uid,$users)) {

        // ... create a user entry ...
        $user = new stdClass();
        $user->firstname = $row->firstName;

        // ... and add it to the user array.
        $users[$uid] = $user;

    }

    // if this row has a valid game ...
    if (!empty($row->game_id)) {

        // ... create a game entry ...
        $game = new stdClass();
        $game->id = $row->game_id;
        $game->name = $row->gameName;

        //.. and add the game to the user's entry
        $users[$uid]->games[$game->id]=$game;

    }

}
```

For a structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Jane
            [games] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Leage of Legends
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Minecraft
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Fred
            [games] => Array
                (
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Dota 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Alex
            [games] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Minecraft
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => War Dragons
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Fortnite
                        )

                )

        )

)
```