# adding a column from a table to another in SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table called 'auditlog' which contains the columns (id, user, action project, info, time, project_ref, workpackage_ref, partner_ref)

and i have another table called 'role' which contains the following columns (id, role, description)

i want to select the whole 'auditlog' table in addition to that i want the 'role' column from 'role' table to be the 3rd column in my selection, and the rest won't be changed

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.user,
r.role,
a.action,
a.project,
a.info,
a.time...
FROM auditlog a
LEFT JOIN role r ON r.id = a.id
```

Comment: it works but there is a problem, that one user can have more then one role and more than once action, how can i collecting them in one row instead of showing me for example 10 rows for the same user but everytime we have a different role and a different action
@samuel Wahlberg

Comment: What is the connection between the 'auditlog' and 'roles' tables? I assumed the id was the userid but not I think it's not. I think you should look a bit more into db design. Look at 'one to many' and 'many to many' relationships.
Check the first respons in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN in sql.

```
SELECT a.*,r.role FROM auditlog AS a LEFT JOIN role AS r ON a.id=r.id
```

You should edit this as your logic.