# How to delete parent entity when deleting child?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes, Parent and Child. I would like to delete the parent entity when removing a child. Note that child should not know about the parent, so I couldn't add backreference.

```
        @Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    private Child child;
}

    @Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

After edit
This way it still not working

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    private Child child;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: are you sure, you don't mix up anything?? In your model: "child can exist without parent"/can have MANY parents!  but "parent can't exist without child"/has min/max/exactly one child...

Comment: Yes I am sure, in my case Child can be used in other entities as well

Comment: ..it is ok (it happened at least once in evolution! ..the "first child" had probably "no parent";), but the naming is confusing! (for english speakers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) it solved my problem

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Child child;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about deleting parent record when child record is deleted then you must use Cascade annotation.

Comment: Sorry @Nadim it still not working after adding Cascade annotation. I have updated the post

Comment: Just check the answer posted by xeex593 read the tutorial then you will fix it by yourself as per your need. Read both bi-directional and uni-directional

Answer (score 0):

Make the relation "bi-directional" by adding:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Parent> parents;
```

.. to "`Child`", and add a `cascade` to that. (So a `delete` of a `Child` will cascade the removal of all it's `Parent`s.)

- [Difference Between One-to-Many, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3113885/592355)
- [When Vlad says so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613450/592355)