# How to do relationship one to many from one side?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Applogise for image! I did datatable structure like this image. How to get Users data from City side. I used laravel.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between One-to-Many, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a One to Many relationship.

In the City model define a function that return a hasMany relation.

```
public function users(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

In the User model define the inverse of this function

```
public function city(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}
```

Don't forget to import

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
```

classes.

After that you are free to use this functions ex:

```
 $users = $city->users() //$city is an instance of City:class
```

Also read the documentation for more information: [Laravel Eloquent Relationships Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)