# How to make relationship between two tables in laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, foreign-keys, relationship

my database has two tables "games" and "teams".

games migration:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('homeTeam');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('awayTeam');
$table->foreign('homeTeam')->references('id')->on('teams')
$table->foreign('awayTeam')->references('id')->on('teams')
```

what is relationship between this two table? many to many?
should I create "game_team" pivot table?

i tried to change the design of the database but it didn't fix it

Comment: Depends. It might be obvious because of the table name but you can reference in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you describe is two 1:n relationships.
A game has one home team and one away team.
You don't need an additional table.

You should use names with _id suffix for foreign keys because laravel models like it that way.

```
Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    // Other game columns
    $table->foreignId('home_team_id');
    $table->foreignId('away_team_id');

    $table->foreign('home_team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
    $table->foreign('away_team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
});
```

In your Game model you can then say

```
public function home_team(): BelongsTo
{
    $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'home_team_id');
}

public function away_team(): BelongsTo
{
    $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'away_team_id');
}
```

to use it like

```
$game = \App\Models\Game::first();
$team1 = $game->home_team;  // get the home team
$team2 = $game->away_team;  // get the away team
```

That is the magic of laravel (eloquent).

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

More details are needed for a more accurate design of the database, but anyway, according to your explanation, the relationship between the games and teams table must be `one-to-many` .

actually you need two one-to-many relation . Each game has two foreign keys, one for the home team and another for the away team, which both reference the `id` column in the `teams` table. that each game belongs to one home team and one away team, and each team can have multiple games associated with it.

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    // Other teams columns
});


Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    // Other game columns
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('home_team');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('away_team');
    $table->foreign('home_team')->references('id')->on('teams');
    $table->foreign('away_team')->references('id')->on('teams');
});
```