Spring Data JPA duplicates record with @OneToMany relationship
I have following entities with one to many relationship. The view returns data properly by joining 2 tables as shown below:
#   id     address_id       order     number
---------------------------------------------
1   1       1               1         101
2   1       2               2         102
3   1       3               3         103
4   1       4               4         104

However, when I retrieve data from this view via repository, it repeats the first column:
#   id     address_id       order     number
---------------------------------------------
1   1       1               1         101
2   1       1               1         101
3   1       1               1         101
4   1       1               1         101

Here is the entities and view below (entities and views are simplified for clarity):
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User(

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val addressList: Set<Address> = emptySet()
    
    // other fields ...

) : AbstractAuditingEntity() // it has equals-hashCode methods and id field with `@Id` annotation

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
class Address(

    @Column(name = "order")
    var order: Long? = null,
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    var user: User,

    @Column(name = "number")
    var number: Long
    
    // other fields ...
    
) : AbstractAuditingEntity() // it has equals-hashCode methods and id field with `@Id` annotation

And I am trying to retrieve data from the following db view and map to the following class:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_user_address
AS SELECT u.id,
    a.id AS address_id,
    a.order,
    a.number
   FROM user u
     LEFT JOIN address a ON a.user_id = u.id;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "view_user_address")
data class ViewUserAddress(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "address_id")
    val addressId: Long,

    @Column(name = "order")
    val order: Long,

    @Column(name = "number")
    val number: Long
)

So, how to fix this problem? I tried to use different annotation e.g. FetchType.LAZY but none of them worked.
Update: The following approach seems to solve the problem:
data class ViewUserAddressId(
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val addressId: Long= 0L
) : Serializable


@Entity
@Immutable
@IdClass(ViewUserAddressId::class)
@Table(name = "view_user_address")
data class ViewUserAddress(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "address_id")
    val addressId: Long,

    @Column(name = "order")
    val order: Long,

    @Column(name = "number")
    val number: Long
)


Hold on, why are you using the third table here? If you are using the OneToMany relationship you don't need a third table. In the case of ManyToMany relationship between objects is the third table needed. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924648/13842927

@Sanady_ I know, but we have a server side filtering that requires entity type and I wanted to retrieve data from a database view to this third entity. So, do you have any idea about the solution of the problem?

Probably try to retrieve data into Set. The set is skipping duplicities or try to filter out the duplicity records using streams, when you fetch data from the database, that's the only possible solution that requires additional computing...

The problem is retrieving the same records for the rest of the other list items. Normally it should return 4 items based on this example, but it repeats by the count of the corresponding records joined.

It is hard to determine in which area is the issue when the whole concept is wrong. I would delete this third entity called view_user_address, because it is the same as the address entity that you posted. Filtering could be done with two entities too. Try to update the question with the whole model and add a service that is sending write requests to the DB.

Thanks, but the third entity is not the same and I just simplified it by removing unnecessary columns. I add the service method where I call repository.

By the way, the problem most probably related to @Id annotation or some entity relationships between these 2 entities.

You could try adding a custom query above the findAll method that returns a generic Page object and just add DISTINCT at the end. That will skip duplicities. @Query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM view_user_address")

I tried before, but in that case I would probably need a projection that is not suitable for my server side search method. So, is there a way to use custom query and map it to ViewUserAddress ? Could you please post an example?

If I understand you correctly, then you could use query annotation in the ReadOnlyRepository interface, something like this: @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM   view_user_address", nativeQuery = true) and that could look like this: `@NoRepositoryBean
interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID> : Repository<T, ID> {
fun findAll(): List<T>

@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM view_user_address", nativeQuery = true)
fun findAll(pageable: Pageable): Page
}`

Here is also article: https://trifork.nl/blog/spring-data-native-queries-and-projections-in-kotlin/

I will try it, on the other hand when I use a composite Id, it worked. I post this approach, if you have any suggestion with this solution feel free to share your suggestions. Thanks.

If the second update is solving your issue then your issue is resolved.

With the help of your helps of course, thanks a lot. By the way, do I need to add a constraint to the user and address entities? I am not sure this approach is exactly the same as I was using in Java with @Embedded and @EmbeddedId. If I can replace the solution with this (not used in Kotlin), I will. What do you think?

IdClass annotation is used to create the composite identifier using the fields of the same entity on which this annotation is applied. @EmbeddedId allows you to separate the fields that are part of the composite key in a separate class.

Then I can proceed with using IdClass
