# is it possible to have a unique on a group of rows instead of entire table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grouped_executions (
    id             INTEGER UNSIGNET NOT NULL ,
    execution_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES execution.execution_id ,
    president      BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

    PRIMARY KEY ( id, execution_id )
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

all i want is to make president unique in a group of rows with same id.

for example: i have such data:

```
id | execution_id | president
= - = - = - = - = - = - = - =
1  | 1            | 0
1  | 2            | 1
1  | 3            | 0
1  | 4            | 0
```

i want mysql prevents inserting new row with id = 1 & president = 1

**( of course i can make another table that holds president of a group but is above structure possible? )**

Comment: I think a better design is like you said, set it in another table.

Comment: yeah! i'm going to make another table :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to set default NULL for `president` as unique key allows multiple `NULL` values, but then, it kind of make no sense to have a `bool` with only one `1` and many `NULL`s, but no `0`. If you don't want to set other mechanisms like triggers (suggested by @David Hedlund), you better of with another table for that relationship (as you mentionned it). This way, if you one day wants a unique "secretary" or "treasury", it would be easy to define a new table instead of having that trigger (or another one) verify for this relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add a unique-constraint for the combination of the two columns.

- [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: but i have many rows with id = 1 & president = 0, if i do "UNIQUE KEY `grouped_executions_id_president` ( `id`, `president` )" i can't have em

Comment: oh, sorry, I got your question wrong, then. I don't know that you can specify uniqueness only for specific values like that in MySQL (I could be wrong). A workaround might be using a trigger to validate an insert or update.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
ALTER TABLE grouped_executions ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (id, president);
```

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE grouped_executions ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (id, president);  
ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined