# MYSQL Query help : If exists update

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

I am making a daily counter for a blog and I have problem with this query :

```
IF EXISTS SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE blog_id=1
    UPDATE FROM tableA SET c=c+'1' WHERE blog_id='1' AND c_date=NOW()
ELSE
    INSERT INTO FROM tableA VALUES (blog_id,c,c_date) VALUES (1,1,now())
```

its showing following error :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'IF EXISTS SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE blog_id=1 UPDATE FROM
>   tableA SET c=c+'' at line 1

```
My table entries should look like this :
id , blod_id , c , c_date
1 , 1001, 66 , 2011-11-11 
2 , 1001, 160 , 2011-11-12
3 , 1002, 200 , 2011-11-12
4 , 1003, 33 , 2011-11-12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're lokoing for the `insert into on duplicate key update` syntax

From the manual:

> 12.2.5.3. INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax
>
> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a
>   duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old
>   row is performed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Your query should look more like the following example:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (blog_id,c,c_date) VALUES (1,1,now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `c` = `c`+1, `c_date` = NOW()
```

You need to have a `UNIQUE` key or a `PRIMARY KEY` for this to work.

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
```

---

Based on your table example you could add a primary key to the `id` column or add a unique composite index on the `(c_date, blog_id)` fields

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` ADD UNIQUE (
blog_id ,
c_date
);
```

and use this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (blog_id, c, c_date) 
  VALUES (1, 1, NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  c = c + 1                --- update only `c`, not any part of the unique key
```

Comment: Thanks but your query is showing same error as mine : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (1,1,now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `c` = `c`+1, `c_date` = NOW()' at line 1

Comment: I fixed the error but I have new problem . its inserting multiple records instead of updating it ...

Comment: Do you have a unique index on the table? You must have a unique field on the row, be it a `UNIQUE` index or a `PRIMARY KEY`. When you try and insert something which is a duplicate of the unique one it will update, otherwise it'll insert.

Comment: no I don't have , but neither blog_id and nor c_date are not unique , if u see that sample table that i added to the question you can see counter is based on the day , mean each blog_id has a daily counter which is used for reports ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me what you really want is [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (beware, it only works with MySQL)!

Comment: thanks but how can I use where in there ? I have edited the question and you can see a sample table which I am going to have it .

Comment: Ben Swinburne's answer is ok but you have to put a unique index on blog_id (so I think your sample is wrong as you have 1001 twice)

Comment: blog_id 1001 has different counter_date ... counter_date will be used in getting reports ...

Comment: Right I didn't notice. You have to put an unique index on blog_id AND c_date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: it doesn't work , as I said to Ben neither blog_id no c_date are not unique ,  I tried to make these two fields unique but it didn't work , after following ur suggestion its showing this error after third query : #1062 - Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'blog_id'