# Avoiding inserting duplicate rows in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with an `auto_inc` id (primary key).
I am trying to avoid the insertion of duplicate rows.

Example of a duplicate row:

```
id  | field a | field b | field c |
1       4          6         7
2       4          6         7
```

The key (`id`) is not duplicate since it is automatically generated by MySQL, but all other fields are identical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make a unique index on fields a,b,c.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (
`a` ,
`b` ,
`c`
);
```

Comment: but the fields are not unique, for example it is fine to have field a=6 many times, what is not allowed is the combination of same values for a,b,c

Comment: That is exactly what this does ;-) Its a combined key, not three separate keys.

Comment: do you know how I can remove this unique index?

Answer (score 9):

You should use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)  and declaring the fields as unique .

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

Comment: but the field is not unique, for example it is fine to have field a=6 many times, what is not allowed is the combination of same values for a,b,c

Comment: You should create a compound unique index : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 3):

You can use this also.

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` ( `field1`, `field2`,`field3`)
SELECT `field1`, `field2`,`field3` FROM `tableName`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM `tableName`
    WHERE 
    `field1` = 'value' AND `field2` = 'value'  AND `field3` = 'value'
    );
```

Comment: How could I do with dynamic value?, instead of SELECT 1, something like select * WHERE

Answer (score -2):

Make the three columns composite key.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ This has been fixed as of 20 June 2013. However, this answer was never needed as Lennart's answer on 6 Jan 2012 10:52 UTC took care of this already!