# how to insert unique product name which belongs to different category and department using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, unique-constraint, unique-key

In my project I have product_details, categories, departments table.

product_details belongs to categories and departments table and categories has many product_details and departments has many product_details.

Am trying to insert product details using nodejs.
I have structured product_name as unique to avoid redundancy. If product with same belongs to different category or departments it is throwing an error and it is not saving those product details. But I want to store the product details with same which belongs to different category or different department. How to do this. If I remove unique constraint then redundancy occurs.

What i want if product with name belongs to same category and same department i don't want save those details, if product with same name belongs to different category and different department i want to save those details. Please help me how achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you very much @LinusGThiel. That link helped me to fix the issue. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the link [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql) given by Linus G Thiel I solve this problem.

```
alter table product_details add unique index (name,category_id,department_id);
```

It is working fine.