# How do I enforce uniqueness in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have to program an enrolment table which has:

1. enrolment_id
2. academic_period
3. results
4. student_id
5. subject

I want to enforce to make sure that a student can't enroll in a subject more than once in a specific academic period.
So, the constraint shall involve student_id, subject, and academic period columns.

I'm still unsure how do I make this happen. Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a unique constraint to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname UNIQUE (student_id, subject, academic_period)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a [unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635937/27535) on `academic_period, student_id, subject`
I'll let you work out the actual SQL

Note: this is *correctly* your natural key: `enrolment_id` is a surrogate added at implementation time because of the database architecture. It isn't mandated in any design or modelling process

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique constraint.  From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp):

> To allow naming of a UNIQUE constraint, and for defining a UNIQUE
>   constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:
>
> MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
 (
 P_Id int NOT NULL,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Address varchar(255),
 City varchar(255),
 CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
 )
```

(Modify the above for the column(s) you need to set as unique)

Answer (score 0):

You would just get the amount of rows returned from this example query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrollment WHERE student_id = 'XYZ' AND subject = 'ABC' AND academic_period = 'DEF'`

If the amount of rows returned is greater than 0, they have already been enrolled in that subject in the academic period.

Comment: This can return 0 falsely because of concurrency effects, especially when using InnoDB which uses MVCC