# sql unique column w

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have simple table which looks like below one:

```
id   info   user     start_date            end_date              resource_id
31   NULL   aorlik   2018-01-04 08:00:00   2018-01-04 10:00:00   1
32   NULL   aorlik   2018-01-04 15:00:00   2018-01-04 17:00:00   1
```

and now I'm looking for simple way for make column start_date as unique with dependency with column resource_id. I would like to make some kind of protection to avoid set same start_date twice. It should allow only for set the same time record for new resource_id. I suppose that's very easy but I have got stuck :/ 
I use MySQL and mysql-workbench.

Comment: add unique key to your table

Comment: Did you try searching at all? _"I have got stuck"_ does not explain to readers what you already tried and what they should/shouldn't tell you in response. Example duplicate: [How do I enforce uniqueness in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432831/how-do-i-enforce-uniqueness-in-a-table)

Comment: @BibinMatthew yes I was trying with unique key and search for good answer before I have asked my question. Have a nice day dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a constraint, in this case a `unique` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE simple_table -- this defines the table to be altered
ADD UNIQUE -- the constraint type
start_resource(start_date,resource_id);  -- constraint_name(columns used, comma separated)
```