# mysql inserting unique row except the key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| id |  -> primary key, auto_increment
| v1 |
| v2 |
```

I want to make sure that there are no duplicate (v1, v2) pairs on insert. Is it possible via an **SQL** statement? Currently I do a select first and if there 's no result I continue with the insert.

I was wondering if there 's a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind an error coming back from the request (you can handle it in your code or as noted elsewhere do your inserts with `INSERT IGNORE` to totally suppress the error.), you could put a UNIQUE compound index on v1, v2.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
      ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_pair(v1,v2);
```

Comment: Agreed, and some extra info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql since I was in the process of answering

Comment: I wasn't aware of compound indexes :o Makes perfect sense and along with @GrailsGuy suggestion, it 's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! 8 more mins limit to mark the answer :o

Comment: Also you have to specify `not null' when you create those fields

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the way you're doing it is actually the preferred method.  However, you can try to use [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), if you've got the proper constraints on the columns.