# mySQL how to prevent insert unless combination of two columns (fields) are unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

I am new to MySQL and have a table that I am converting to MySQL which contains "order guides" for accounts which are all the items an account normally orders.  I need to prevent an insert in the case of an item (product number) for an account is already in the order guide table which is dependent on the combination of the uniqueness of two fields.  Simplified example of the data in the order guide table:

```
uID  Account_Num   Prod_Num
0    1000          2000
1    1000          2010
2    1000          2020
3    1000          2030
4    1001          2000
5    1001          2010
6    1001          2020
7    1001          2021
```

I can not just make the "Account_Num" and "Prod_Num" fields unique.  I need a way to set a rule or something to specify if the combination of "Account_Num" and "Prod_Num" are unique allow insert.  The uID field is a unique auto increment field.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be delighted to know that indexes can be multi-column :-)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE account_prod (Account_Num, Prod_Num);
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Thanks! I did not realize that the unique index acts as a rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
create unique index mytable_idx1 on mytable(Account_Num, Prod_Num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Have a look at

```
INSERT INTO <yourtable> (cols)
  SELECT cols FROM <yourtable2>, <yourtable> where <yourcondition>
```

Make sure that the select only returns new entries.