# java, mysql compare and edit values

Tags: java, mysql, comparison

I`m building a decision support system in java. Below is a part of code, that scans the search word that is typed in by user, then compares it with database searchlog.searchcolumn values and if the word is not there creates a new entry. BUT in the if statement i want it to check for the entry, and if it IS already in searchlog.searchcolumn column, then I want it  NOT to create a new duplicate entry, but to add +1 value to searchlog.counter column for the specific word.
for example if search word is "UMBRELLA" and there is already one entry for umbrella in database, i want it to add +1 to counter column in UMBRELLA row.

the purpose of this, is to store all searchwords and keep a track of the most popular ones.
Thank you for your time
        String CheckSearch = "SELECTsearchcolumn FROMsearchlog";

```
String InsertColumn = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`searchlog` (`searchcolumn`) VALUES ('"+ InputScanner + "'); 
         //
if (InputScanner.equals(CheckSearch)) 
   System.out.println("value ealready exist, counter well be updated"); 
else
   stmt.executeUpdate(InsertColumn);
```

**EDIT**
Thank you for advice of using PreparedStatement, but this is my first more or less serious challenge and for this time, let`s just ignore vulnerability of my code. Thanks

Comment: At a glance, if you're developing a system (decision support system as you say) then you must use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to mitigate SQL injection attacks or use an ORM model like Hibernate or JPA along with a controller to achieve a complete MVC architecture, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for advice of using PreparedStatement, but this is my first more or less serious challenge and for this time, let`s just ignore vulnerability of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database are you using? If you are using MySQL, then you should look into `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. (Other SQL databases have `MERGE`, which I'm less familiar with.) Here is the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

You will need make your `searchcolumn` a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` column, then something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO searchlog (searchcolumn, count) VALUES ("my search query", 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

will accomplish what you want.

Comment: it looks like it works, but i have autoincrement ID column in same table which, using this query, increases by1 each time statement is executed. Ex. if umbrella is searched 10times, id becomes 11 instead of 2

Comment: If your usage case already dictates that the <code>searchcolumn</code> must be unique, I don't see why you need a second autoincrement column. However, if you must have the autoincrement as well, you just need to make the combination of the two columns unique. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

your query should be :

```
String InsertColumn = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`searchlog` (`searchcolumn`) VALUES ('"+ InputScanner + "'");
```

Values clause should also be wrapped around brackets.

and always use equals() to check if two strings are meaningfully equal. In case of objects `==` checks if two reference variables refer to the same object.

```
      if (InputScanner == CheckSearch) {

should be:

      if (InputScanner.equals(CheckSearch)) {
```

Then, your if statement would return true if InputScanner is same as checkSearch.

### ADVICE:

I strongly recommend you to use [**PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than simple Statement to prevent SQL Injection.

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.preparedStatement(InsertColumn);
st.setString(1, val1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Values also need to be in braces

Example:

```
VALUES ('"+ InputScanner + "');
```

2) Assuming `InputScanner` and `CheckSearch` are Strings/comparable objects, you need to do `.equals()` instead of `==`

Example:

```
if (InputScanner.equals(CheckSearch)) {
```

Note: Your SQL statement is prone to SQL Injection attack. Better to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [MySQL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for your task:

Requierement: `searchcolumn` is a unique key.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.searchlog(searchcolumn, counter) VALUES(?, 1) "
    + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.createPreparedStatement(sql);
stmt.setParameter(1, checkSearch.toUpperCase());
int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I do not know whether `updateCount` distinghuishes whether an INSERT or UPDATE happened though. You could use `getGeneratedKeys` for that purpose, if there is a unmentioned AUTOINCR primary key.