# @Stateless webservice with JPA+JTA: How to commit changes of managed entity?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jax-rs, jta

I have the following simple webservice declared as `@Stateless` EJB running on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with EclipseLink 2.4.1 using a JTA `DataSource` to connect to a MySQL database:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update(TimeRow e) throws Exception {
    if ((e.getKey() == null) || !e.getKey().keyValid()) {
        return Response.status(400).build();
    }

    TimeRow existing = em.find(TimeRow.class, e.getKey());
    if (existing == null) {
        em.persist(e);
    } else {
        existing.setValues(e.getValues());
        em.flush();
    }
    return Response.status(204).build();
}
```

Entity class of `TimeRow`:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="TimeRow.findAllByUser",
         query="SELECT t FROM TimeRow t WHERE t.table.userId = :uid")
})
public class TimeRow implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TimeRowPK key;

    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    @ManyToOne
    private UserTable table;
    @Column(name="ROWVALUES")
    private List<Double> values;

    public TimeRow() {
        this.key = new TimeRowPK();
        this.values = new ArrayList<Double>(20);
        extendValuesTo20();
    }

    public TimeRow(String uid, Date date) {
        this.key = new TimeRowPK(date, uid);
        this.table = new UserTable(uid);
        this.values = new ArrayList<Double>(20);
        extendValuesTo20();
    }

    public List<Double> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Double> values) {
        this.values = values;
        extendValuesTo20();
    }

    private void extendValuesTo20() {
        if (this.values.size() < 20) {
             for (int i = this.values.size(); i < 20; i++) {
                  this.values.add(0.0);
             }
        }
    }

}
```

`@EmbeddableId` `TimeRowPK`:

```
@Embeddable
public class TimeRowPK implements Serializable {

    public TimeRowPK() { }

    public TimeRowPK(Date date, String userId) {
        this.date = date;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name="DAY")
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private String userId;

    public boolean keyValid() {
        return ((date != null) && ((userId != null) && !userId.isEmpty()));
    }

}
```

`persistence.xml` (without the `<persistence>` tag):

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.test.TimeRow</class>
    <class>com.test.TimeRowPK</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Webservice declaration:

```
@Path("row")
@Stateless
public class TimeRowWebService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
    private EntityManager em;

    ...

}
```

The problem is that if the entity exists, the changes get stored only in the `PersistenceContext`, but they are not committed to the database. Meaning that I can retrieve the correct data with the changes, but for example if I restart the AS, the changes are gone. There are no errors in the AS log.

So I guess I have to do some bean level manual transaction handling to get this work. What exactly do I have to add to get this working?

Comment: Is the bean declared @Stateless?

Comment: In this case I can't see an error here... `@Stateless` implies `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` if you don't change it... Maybe it resides in the `MyEntity.setValues()` or in the `MyEntity` declaration itself. Can you post the `MyEntity` code?

Comment: @CarloPellegrini I've added the actual entity class with it's `@EmbeddedId` class. I've removed some getters to make it shorter.

Comment: What type of EntityManager are you using ? Application or Container-managed one ?

Comment: Show us how you obtain EntityManager, how does the persistence.xml looks like and the WebService class annotations (or DD).

Comment: @Gab Container-managed if I'm not mistaken. I use @PersistenceContext to inject, and I get an exception if I try to manually call `em.getTransaction().begin()` saying I am not allowed to use `EntityTransaction` if using a JTA datasource.

Comment: I don't really remember about persisting lists of basic types - can you e.g. try adding `@ElementCollection` to your values property? (don't remember if it's added implicitly or not)  
The transaction should be committed during business method execution, so it should be working...

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Tried `@ElementCollection`, but I got the same error. Also strangely enough the list is reversed :)

Comment: Can it be a problem that I'm injecting with `@PersistenceContext` in multiple webservices?

Comment: No it should not be a problem. Can you test if some basic value is updated? Right now you're testing it only with list of basic types; can you edit some direct field of your entity (add one for tests) and see if it gets updated and persisted?

Comment: No Container properly manage EM scope across the multiple injection points. The right question is what is the JTA transaction scope in a restfull app.
JPA JSR extract :  When a container-managed entity manager is used, the lifecycle of the persistence context is always managed automatically, transparently to the application, and the persistence context is propagated with the JTA transaction

Comment: You can't commit which means there is a rollback of the transaction which means there is definitely an error. Can you please enable logging in persistence ? Regards,

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Tried it with a basic `Double` field, and had the same phenomenon. Also, I noticed that the value change gets consolidated in DB if I change in the same 'session' where the entity was persisted.

Comment: I suspect that this is something with the `@EmbeddedId`. I have another entity class which uses an auto-generated `@Id` with a `List<String>` property and it works properly. I will try to change `@EmbeddedId` to a composite key implementation with `@Id`.

Comment: Perhaps it has something do to with your `date` part of embeddedPK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling to get this working the `@EmbeddedId` way, I've tried to implement it by using a generated `@Id`, and adding a unique constraint for the two key fields afterwards.

**Entity**

```
public class TimeRow implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private UserTable table;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DAY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="ROWVALUES")
    private List<Double> values;

    ...
}
```

Additionally, I've changed the DB engine from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` to have better foreign key support. To do this, I've added `default-storage-engine = innodb` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section.

After generating the DB structure with DDL, I've [added a unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql) for `USERID` and `DAY`:

```
alter table TIMEROW add unique index(USERID,DAY);
```

Now it works and data is modified correctly :) A huge thank you to everybody who contributed to this question!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the catch is here:

```
public void setValues(List<Double> values) {
    this.values = values;
    extendValuesTo20();
}
```

Try to change it to use the container's list as in:

```
public void setValues(List<Double> values) {
    this.values.clear();
    this.values.addAll(values);
    extendValuesTo20();
}
```

Also, it's a very strange use of JPA. I've never seen lists persisted this way without `@ElementCollection`