# Set Unique pair of columns in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on project with **php-MySQL** in the back-end.It has various **articles** to browse,sorted into various **categories** and a **user-login** system.
I recently added a **watch-list functionality** to it which enables users to **add articles to their watch-list/dashboard**.
I have the following tables.

> **Articles** table
>   
> article-id(int) Primary-Unique 
>   
> cat(varchar)
> name(varchar)
> subCat(varchar)
> description(varchar)
> date added
>   **users** table
> username(varchar) Primary-Unique 
> lname
> fname
> joined-date
>   .**Watchlist** table
>   
> article-id(int)
> username(varchar)
> date_watch

As we can see there is no unique key for watch-list table
I want to make **(username + article-id)** a unique pair 
Because for every username more than 1 article-id's exist and viceversa

I just want to **insert** and **delete** rows and It's **not needed to update** them
how to **prevent duplicate entries?**
 till now I have been checking number of rows with php

```
"SELECT * FROM watchlist WHERE article-id={$id} AND username={$user}"
```

and if

```
mysql_num_rows() >1(not allowed to insert)
```

This works fine but if by mistake that INSERT command is executed thare will be a duplicate entry
How to prevent it?
 I am using **phpmyadmin**

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply add a unique key to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `watchlist`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `watchlist_unique` (`article-id`, `username`);
```

Also, looking at the functionality of what you have, you may as well opt for setting it as your primary key, by using this instead of the above:

```
ALTER TABLE `watchlist`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`article-id`, `username`);
```

Both will prevent any insertion of a duplicate entry.

In addition, if you want to insert in this case, you may want to check out INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY. For more info on both see ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update).

Comment: one thing to be noticed is that if any unique index have defined on `article-id` or `username` before this, they must be removed to allow this rule works well for cases such as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM watchlist WHERE article-id={$id} AND username={$user}";
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >=1) {
     //Prevent Insert 
} else {
     //Put your Insert query
}
```

Or simply use `IGNORE` like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO watchlist
    (article-id, username)
VALUES
    ({article-id}, {username}),
```

Makesure that you are using the columns as `UNIQUE` constraints.If not change them as like

```
ALTER TABLE `watchlist`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `watchlist_unique`
(`username`,`article-id`);
```

You need to check `atleast` of `1` record not greater than `1`.

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: If you read his original posting, your solution is exactly what he tried. He wants an insurance in case he mistakenly inserts the same details into his database.

Comment: @Sutandiono have you checked my ans entirely..??I gave diff solutuion from him.

Comment: I have told him to check with `>=` and also using `IGNORE`..see it

Comment: Okay, I missed the `=` sign at `>=`. As for `INSERT IGNORE`, you will still need to add the `UNIQUE` constrains which tells the DB which columns are considered unique.

Comment: @Sutandiono thanks for your suggestion.I will try to explore MySQLi later.But for now what should I prefer.Checking number of rows or the answer posted by @ellie(create unique pair). Which is better?

Comment: You should do both. Check the number of rows in PHP to prevent duplicate entry, and add `UNIQUE INDEX` in your database as a backup in case someone later tries to insert data straight into the table, bypassing your PHP script.

Comment: Yes Iam doing it for both the fields

Answer (score 0):

You can make a unique index on username and article-id:

```
ALTER TABLE watchlist ADD UNIQUE INDEX my_idx ( username, article-id);
```

Then no duplicate inserts will be permitted.

You can also handle duplicate inserts gracefully with the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax, to update certain fields in the entry with the given username, article-id pair.