# Uniqueness check for multiple values in column DB

Tags: mysql

I know about creating unique index. But My problem is bit different.
I want uniqueness check for different states for the same column.

For example.
Table contains column Money_Transfer_status, now it can be pending, in_progress, approved, rejected etc.

Now for a given user if there is an in_progress or pending status I do not want to add new money transfer for the user, else it should be okay.

Is there some way in DB I can specify this?

Comment: Duplicate. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql?rq=1).

Comment: @RossPresser, That isn't a duplicate. The referenced question is about multiple columns as part of a unique key. This question is about considering multiple values for one column as being the same when checking for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a before insert trigger on your table.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND money_trans_status = 'pending')
THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'pending money transfer...';
END IF;
END $$
```

Then your insert statement gets aborted.

Read more about signals [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

EDIT: Two things to note though, it will also behave like this:

```
insert into your_table values ('valid_value'); -- succeeds as expected
insert into your_table values ('non-valid_value'); -- fails as expected

insert into your_table ('valid_value'), ('non_valid_value'), ('valid_value'); -- everything fails as one row is bad
```

and you will need at least MySQL version 5.5