# MySql unique field by foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Im Not sure if this question already been asked, because I think my question is not really clear...

Let say i have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EntrepriseSpecialites
(
    id_EntrepriseSpecialite INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,id_Entreprise INT
    ,id_Specialite INT UNIQUE
);
```

At the moment, i can only have one id_Specialite with the same value in my table, but does there is a way to only an unique id_Specialite by id_Entreprise.

Example :

```
    id_EntrepriseSpecialite | id_Entreprise | id_Specialite
    1 | 1 | 1
    2 | 2 | 1
    3 | 2 | 4
    4 | 2 | 1 <- ops id_Entreprise 2 already have the id_Specialite 1
    5 | 3 | 1
```

Comment: Why not make `id_Entreprise` and `id_Speciatelite` your `Composite Primary Key` so that it would always be unique?

Comment: I suppose you just want a compound `UNIQUE` constraint on two columns: `id_Entreprise` and `id_Specialite` - check this thread: [UNIQUE on more than one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Why not make `d_Entreprise` and `id_Specialite` as your c`ompound/composite Primary Key`, like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EntrepriseSpecialites
(
 id_Entreprise INT
 ,id_Specialite INT
 , PRIMARY KEY (id_Entreprise, id_Specialite)
);
```

See [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6bd1)