# MySQL Insert Where Record Does Not Already Exist In PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im using PDO (PHP Data Objects) for database interactions from PHP. This question concerns three database tables: two are just standard tables with primary keys, and the other is a table to describe relations between those other two tables. As such it has no primary key, but 2 foreign key columns (table_1_id and table_2_id). Neither can be unique as there is a many to many relationship between records in the other two tables.

To determine if a relationship should be added, I need to insert a record only if there is not already a row in the relational table which matches both table_1_id AND table_2_id.

Ideally my insert would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (table_1_id, table_2_id) VALUES (:id1, :id2)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_3 WHERE table_1_id = :id1 AND table_2_id = :id2
)
```

However, I know this is not valid SQL.
I have looked around a bit and can't determine the best way to do this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just make sure you got the right database engine otherwise the following answers won't work. FWIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** you better define a composite PK `(table_1_id, table_2_id)` explicitly in `table_3`

```sql
CREATE TABLE table3
(
  table_1_id INT NOT NULL, 
  table_2_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (table_1_id, table_2_id),
  FOREIGN KEY table_1_id REFERENCES table_1 (table_1_id),
  FOREIGN KEY table_2_id REFERENCES table_2 (table_2_id)
)
```

**Secondly** you can then use `IGNORE` clause instead of a sub-query

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_3 (table_1_id, table_2_id) VALUES (:id1, :id2)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3ae0/1)** demo

---

If you were for some reason wanted to stick with a sub-query version then your INSERT statement should've looked something like this

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_3 (table_1_id, table_2_id) 
SELECT ?, ?
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table_3
   WHERE table_1_id = ?
     AND table_2_id = ?
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaf67/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks to all who answered! I didn't know about composite keys. I have learnt something very useful!

I will mark your answer as correct as you have provided a little more explanation and the SQL Fiddle.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a combined primary key

```
ALTER TABLE table_3 ADD PRIMARY KEY(`table_1_id`,`table_2_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation you're talking about is called "Many to Many".

MySql let's you specify more than one column as a unique index, that is, a column combined unique index.

**[Please see this question in SO that has detailed information about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)**.

This prevents you from creating duplicate roles, which is want you want to accomplish.

As for the PHP code, PDO throws an error when a sql statement fails, so you can use try/catch

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define a unique constraint (or primary key) on the combination of the two columns. That's the normative pattern. But that won't allow multiple rows with the same combination of values.

So, assuming you do want to allow "duplicate" rows, but it's just this one INSERT statement you want to not insert a duplicate row, then use a `SELECT` in place of the `VALUES` keyword. Basically, write a SELECT statement that conditionally returns the values.

Something like this might work for you:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (table_1_id, table_2_id) 
SELECT v.id1, v.id2 
  FROM ( SELECT :id1 AS table_1_id, :id2 AS table_2_id ) v
  LEFT
  JOIN table_3 d
    ON d.table_1_id = v.table_1_id
   AND d.table_2_id = v.table_2_id
 WHERE d.table_1_id IS NULL
```