# How to enforce unique constraint on two columns together in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In my mysql table, I store rows which act as walls on a playing field. The table columns are like:

- id
- owner_id
- x
- y

The id column, is the primary key, the owner_id is the foreign key, the x and y are the location of the wall. How can I set a constraint that the x and y columns together be unique?
If I put a unique constraint on both columns, then it will act separately on each column.  This is because I don't want 2 existing walls in the same location. But walls can be destroyed and built on that location again later.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql?

Comment: Someone with that much rep should really know how to check for duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 alter table yourTableName add unique index(x, y);
```

This makes the x, y combination unique, and cannot be duplicated just like any index constraint.