# Unique on Compound Columns

Tags: mysql, key, unique, powerdesigner, compound-key

I am trying to ensure that the values in `RESTAURANTID` and `TABLENUMBER`, **together**, are `Unique` using `PowerDesigner (12.5)`. I've tried creating an `alternate key` which resulted in the following in my `.sql` file:

```
create table TABLES
(
   TABLEID             int not null,
   RESTAURANTID         int not null,
   TABLENUMBER         int not null,
   primary key (TABLESID),
   key AK_mykey (RESTAURANTID, TABLENUMBER)
);
```

However with this, I can still enter identical values for `RESTAURANTID` and `TABLENUMBER` more than once.

I used this http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=403554 to create the `alternate key` in `PowerDesigner`.

Would anyone know the proper way to achieve this in `PowerDesigner`?

**Note:** This isn't a duplicate of the question posted above as I'm looking for a way to achieve this in `PowerDesigner` without having to edit the generated `sql` file afterwards.

Comment: What you are looking for is a composite key constraint. Take a look at this SO post for more information about this kind of key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unique` property for keys (other than primary) in MySQL is stored as an extended attribute on the key.

You can modify it by displaying, and going to the `MySQL` tab in the Key properties dialog.

Or, in `Model>Keys`, you can use the `Customize Columns and Filter` button to show the `Ext Unique` (extended) property in the list of keys, so that you can set this unique property on several keys at once.

Or, you can create your own copy of the MySQL DBMS, and edit it. Under `Profile>Key` (using the right-click), add an event handler `Initialize` with the following `Event Handler Script`, so that each new key has `ExtUnique` set:

```
Function %Initialize%(obj)
   obj.setextendedattribute "ExtUnique",true
   %Initialize% = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding a normal index. What you need is a unique index. Just replace `key AK_mykey (RESTAURANTID, TABLENUMBER)` with `unique key AK_mykey (RESTAURANTID, TABLENUMBER)` in your query and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz. Would you know how to accomplish this only using `PowerDesigner` so I don't need to edit my generated `SQL` file afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, but I never used PowerDesigner. I use phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Designer:

1. Open the "TABLES" table properties (right click -> properties)
2. Keys tab
3. Insert row (name it to "AK_mykey")
4. Apply (previously inserted row saved)
5. On the "AK_mykey" row: right click -> properties
6. Columns tab
7. Add columns button
8. Select the required columns (RESTAURANTID, TABLENUMBER)
9. OK, OK, OK buttons

+1 You can check the result in table properties preview tab.

```
alter table TABLES
   add unique AK_mykey (RESTAURANTID, TABLENUMBER);
```