# Disable mysql insert if two row values repeated

Tags: mysql, duplicates

[image]

I want to disable a mysql insert if two rows have same values. For Example:
If at row 1 title="title1" & url="www.example.com" AND
also at row 2 title="title1" & url="www.example.com"
I want only the first row to be inserted.

**FOUND THE ANSWER:**

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`column1`, `column2`);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: use unique key as title will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before inserting data fire Select query as

```
$s1 = "Select * From your table where title = '$title' and URL = '$URL'";

 $res = mysql_query($s1) or die("!query");

 if(mysql_affected_rows ())
 {
   echo "record exists";
  }
 else
 {
 echo "your insert query";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But what I wanted from MYSQL.. I have found the answer. thanks for your time.