# Preventing Duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, duplicates, duplicate-data

I am currently working on a evolutionary algorithm which will try to find an optimum configuration of parameters for a given problem.

I'm trying to create records in a MySQL table which will store a configuration where each parameter will be represented as a table column. If a configuration has already been attempted then I would like to prevent it from being duplicated.

Is there a mechanism to do this at the database/ORM level or should I create programmatic logic to prevent duplicate entries?

Comment: slap a unique key on the relevant fields in your table?

Comment: The uniqueness will be a combination of all of the columns. I don't think a  primary key will suffice. The look up must be done on all columns when determining whether or not the configuration has been attempted already.

Comment: which is what the unique key does. `alter table foo add unique key (field1, field2, ..., fieldN)`. keys can have multiple fields in them, after all...

Comment: `N` can be large. Knock yourself out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a mechanism to do this at the database/ORM level

Yes, declare or define the `Configuration` column as `Primary Key` or `Unique Key` while you are creating your table to avoid duplication.

I mentioned `configuration` column cause I am not sure about your table structure but if it involves multiple column then you can make it a composite key always. Why you are worried about key lookup. if you design your table properly with proper index then you shouldn't worries about that.

Say your `col1, col2, col3, col4` is part of configuration and you want them to be unique. Then make them as composite primary key saying

```
primary key (col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Comment: Rahul, I don't think that's right the uniqueness will be a combination of all of the columns. A primary key will not suffice as the look up must be done on all columns when determining whether or not the configuration has been attempted already.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign, I mentioned `configuration` column cause I am not sure about your table structure but if it involves multiple column then you can make it a composite key always. Why you are worried about key lookup. if you design your table properly with proper index then you shouldn't worries about that.

Comment: So what is going to prevent me from storing a duplicate configuration with a different primary key? @Rahul

Comment: @PrimeByDesign, BY DBMS concept there can be only one PK per table and so that's not possible. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rahul That is my problem. I need to ensure that a combination of all of the columns are unique in the database

Comment: Does this mean that I have to do this using code logic?

Comment: look what Marc said above. Stop typing here, type it on mysql. Now do it

Comment: @PrimeByDesign, you are getting confused. That's what I said that define or make all the columns involved as composite primary key and DB engine will make sure about uniqueness of them. Consider reading about primary key for more information.

Comment: Ah Rahul! I understand now... ALTER TABLE `votes` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`user`, `email`, `address`); as found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql