# How to model this complex validation for uniqueness on combined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, migration

A `link` has two `components`: `componenta_id` and `componentb_id`. To this end, in the `Link` model file I have:

```
belongs_to :componenta, class_name: "Component"
belongs_to :componentb, class_name: "Component"

validates :componenta_id, presence: true
validates :componentb_id, presence: true
validates :componenta_id, uniqueness: { scope: :componentb_id }
validates :componentb_id, uniqueness: { scope: :componenta_id }
```

And in the migration file:

```
create_table :links do |t|
  t.integer  :componenta_id, null: false 
  t.integer  :componentb_id, null: false
  ...
end
add_index :links, :componenta_id
add_index :links, :componentb_id
add_index :links, [:componenta_id, :componentb_id], unique: true
```

**Question:** This all works. Now I want the combination of `componanta` and `componentb` to be unique, irrespective their order. So irrespective which component is `componenta` and which one is `componentb` (after all that's the same link; a link between the two same components). So the two records below should not be allowed since they represent the same link and thus are not unique:

- componenta_id = 1 ; componentb_id = 2
- componenta_id = 2 ; componentb_id = 1

How can I create this uniqueness validation? I have model validation working (see below) but wonder whether and how I should also add validation at the migration/db level...?

---

**Model validation**
I have model validation working with the code below:

```
before_save :order_links
validates :componenta_id, uniqueness: { scope: :componentb_id }

private
  def order_links
    if componenta_id > componentb_id
      compb = componentb_id
      compa = componenta_id
      self.componenta_id = compb
      self.componentb_id = compa
    end
  end
```

The following test confirms the above works:

```
  1. test "combination of two links should be unique" do
  2.   assert @link1.valid?
  3.   assert @link2.valid?
  4.   @link1.componenta_id = 3     #@link2 already has combination 3-4
  5.   @link1.componentb_id = 4
  6.   assert_not @link1.valid?
  7.   @link1.componenta_id = 4
  8.   @link1.componentb_id = 3
  9.   assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique do
  10.    @link1.save
  11.  end
  12.end
```

---

**Migration/db validation:**
As an extra level of security, is there also a way to incorporate validation for this at the db level? Otherwise it is still possible to write both of the following records to the database: `componenta_id = 1 ; componentb_id = 2` as well as `componenta_id = 2 ; componentb_id = 1`.

Comment: In [this conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql) the suggestion is to create a many-to-many relation:
`has many :components`
`validates_length_of :components,maximum:2`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is possible to control the creation of the links with:

```
def create_unique_link( comp_1, comp_2 )
  if comp_1.id > comp_2.id
    first_component = comp_1
    second_component = comp_2
  end
  link = Link.find_or_create_by( componenta_id: first_comp.id, componentb_id: second_comp.id )
end
```

If you need the validation, then you can custom validate:

```
def ensure_uniqueness_of_link
  if comp_1.id > comp_2.id
    first_component = comp_1
    second_component = comp_2
  end

  if Link.where( componenta_id: first_component.id, componentb_id: second_component ).first
    errors.add( :link, 'Links should be unique' )
  end

end
```

Comment: But that's all model validation, right? For model validation the code as I have it works. It is validation at the db level, so I mean in the migration file, that is still missing.

Comment: I can't think of a generic way at the database level. Perhaps use some form of database trigger to prevent it? There could also be database vendor specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
 validates :componenta_id, uniqueness: { scope: :componentb_id }
 validates :componentb_id, uniqueness: { scope: :componenta_id }
```

Comment: Thanks! but wouldn't this still allow for a combination of 1-2 as well as 2-1. Meaning one time where component with id 1 is `componenta` and the component with id 2 is `componentb`, and one time the other way around? This is what I want to prevent. The combination 1-2 should be unique, irrespective which one of the two is `componenta` and which is `componentb`.

Comment: Yep it will which is why I was going to delete the answer; I thought I'd leave it unless it got voted down :D

Comment: Why not try the above? Not super clever, but might get the result you need

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it. But unfortunately the test added to the post fails on line 9.