# Mysql - Multiple unique sets in a single Column based on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I must create a table for handling student data which has two columns `department code` and `register number`,. *For Eg. dept 101 has 30 students with register numbers (1-30) And dept 102 has 30 different students with same register numbers (1-30)* . for instance.,The student with regno:3 who belongs to dept:101 and another student with regno:3 but in the dept:102 are in same table.,There can be same regno's but different dept code is there a way to relate my two columns.. I have added another image for more clarifications [Table Structure with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGmBP.jpg) **My problem is how can i have unique set register numbers for each deparment in the same column *to avoid duplication***.  The Values of reg_no with **same** Department Code must have a unique set,.. and **another set of regno with a different dept_code must have another or individual set of unique set of numbers**
Can i Have Multiple unique sets in a single Column..??
The
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF7qZ.jpg) sample image

Is there any solution or should i use another table for each dept_code

Tried on Googling didn't Get a result yet . Thanks in Advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.  It is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Yep, need more details. You most certainly do not need to create tables per dept_code. You just should explain in more detail what is You problem? What You want to achieve? What is reg_no? What is dept_code? Is set of dept_code assigned to given reg_no stored in database somwhere?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UNIQUE KEY 'thekey' ('dept','regno');
```

more about the background is found at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql://)