# Mysql Unique record 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I am making an application which inserts users into a MySQL database.

I know you can make a column value unique, but I want a combination of 2 columns in a record to be unique.

For example:

```
id   firstname   lastname    creationdate
-----------------------------------------
 1   John        Doe         (today)
```

What I want to achieve is that I can enter a record like :

```
 2, John, Deo, (today)
```

but I cannot enter:

```
2, John, Doe, (today)
```

What SQL statement can I use to  make a combination of multiple columns unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below query

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (FirstName,LastName)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp