# Restricitng students reappearing in a test they already appeared in online examination system

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make online examination system. I have three tables. Table "student" has details of students, column id identifies students uniquely. Table "tests" has details of all the tests available and there is a column id which contains id of tests. and then I have tables of tests which contains questions and answers.

Now I want that if any student has appeared in a test, it can not reappear in that test again. How can I achieve that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: add usersid and testid to another table

Comment: Take an extra field for status, when a student appear in test make it 1 next time when you process it exclude all records having status 1. thats it.

Comment: You should provide code as to what you have tried. We want to help you find answers to issues not provide free coding services.

Answer (score 0):

Aah.  If you need to create the relation table...  First make a table relating the student_id and the test_id.  When you make this you can make the primary key on multiple columns:

```
CREATE TABLE students_tests
( 
FOREIGN KEY student_id REFERENCES student(id) ,
FOREIGN KEY test_id REFERENCES tests(id)
PRIMARY KEY (student_id,test_id)
)
```

However, if you already have the relation table with a primary key, you can make pairs (or tuples) of keys a unique set with the ALTER TABLE ... ADD UNIQUE command .  This question has been answered here:

[How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)