# Ensuring the unicity of records in a table when importing data from some programs

Tags: python, database

**Abstract question**: When importing a record (= table row) from some programs to a database, I sometimes want to only import the record if and only if the record isn't already present in the database, based on some unique identifier. Is it preferable to:

- first query the database to check whether the record with the same identifier is already present in the database, and if not, insert the record,
- *or* add some [unicity constraint in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635937/395857), then try to insert the record, surrounded by some `try ... catch`

?

---

**Concrete example**: I have a data file containing a list of users. For each user I have a `first name` and `last name`. I assume that two people may not have the same name. I want to write a Python script that inserts the data in a PostgreSQL table, whose columns are `userid` (auto-incremented primary key), `first_name` (text), and `last_name` (text).

I want to insert the user `John Doe`. Is it preferable to:

- first query the database to check whether the record with the same record is already present in the database, and if not, insert the record, e.g.:

  ```
  sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM users WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name`= 'Doe'"
  data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
  if data['cnt'][0]==0:
      sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) values ('John','Doe')"
      cursor.execute(sql)
      connection.commit()
  ```
- *or* add some [unicity constraint in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635937/395857) (on `(first_name, last_name)`), then try to insert the record, surrounded by some `try … catch`, e.g."

  ```
  try:
      sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) values ('John','Doe')"
      cursor.execute(sql)
      connection.commit()
  except:
      print('The user is already present in database')
  ```

?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.