# Many-to-many table with ID and Relation

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to build a database where an admin

> Can create lists that have can have tasks, now the tricky part is, all users can set tasks as completed, but only for himself.

Here's my current scheme

[image]

Is this a correct way of handling this?

Comment: *"all users can set tasks as completed, but only for himself."* This would be part of the application logic, the database wouldn't need to do this, *right?* Or is your question to incorporate this logic into the database layer?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mean the completed field shoud be unique for the user_id and the task_id.

Comment: ...as long as you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `user_id` and `task_id` in `user_tasks` table, then you're good. http://stackoverflow.com/q/635937/3000179

Comment: So it's ok to have an ID field in a many-to-many table and relate that to the user_tasks table? Never done this before, but I don't see any other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `completed` flag, as there wouldn't be a point in adding a row if the task wasn't completed

```
create table user_list_tasks_completion (
  user_id int references users(user_id),
  list_task_id int references list_tasks(id),
  primary key (user_id, list_task_id)
);
```