# SQL ON DUPLICATE KEY with 2 unique keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that goes like so:

```
+----+--------+-------+-------------+
| id | userID | month | lastUpdated |
+----+--------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |      5 |     1 | 2017-03-27  |
|  2 |      5 |     2 | 2017-03-22  |
|  3 |      5 |     3 | 2017-03-21  |
|  4 |      9 |     1 | 2017-03-27  |
|  5 |      9 |     2 | 2017-03-22  |
|  6 |      9 |     3 | 2017-03-21  |
+----+--------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to make an `INSERT` statement to this table but use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_last_updated
(userID, month, lastUpdated)
VALUES
(:userID, :month, :lastUpdated)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastUpdated = :lastUpdated
```

The thing is, a `userID` can show up multiple times and a `month` value can show up multiple times BUT, the uniqueness of each row is a combination of `userID` & `month` (e.g: `userID = 1` & `month = 3` can only appear once).

Is there a way to make a combination of 2 columns to be unique?

Thanks :)

Comment: Set userID , month as PK

Comment: Create unique index on multiple columns - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: But can't there be only 1 PK per table? the AI 'id' is already set as PK

Comment: no it can be muti-PK per table

Comment: PK not exactly  equals `unique index`. You can have just 1 PK, but multiple  unique indexes (composite or single column) per table

Comment: @RomanHocke Thanks, it works like magic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the unique key is userid/month, then use both of those for a unique index or constraint:

```
create index unq_users_last_updated_2 on users_last_updated(userId, month);
```

I would add that it seems strange to have `month` without a `year`.

The `on duplicate key` uses any and all available unique indexes, including primary keys (but not limited only to primary keys).