# Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists without a unique key

Tags: mysql

I know there is one way to accomplish this result using a unique key, for example ID, but as you can see below in my case this won't work because I don't have one unique key.

```
INSERT INTO User_Status (User_ID1, User_ID2, Status) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status = ?
```

The thing is I don't have one unique ID on this tabel, however there are 3 current options. 1) Twoo users don't have one status together, in other words: INSERT it in the tabel. 2) User 1 has one status with user 2 (The 1-2 combination however IS UNIQUE). 3) Same as case 2, but turned around: user 2 has one status with user 1 ( Again this combination IS UNIQUE).

Is there anyway to Update if it already Exist with this options?

**Sample Data:**

```
User_ID1     User_ID2     Status
1            4            has_send_request
4            1            has_received_request
4            2            friends
2            4            friends
```

Let's say I want to update the status of user 1-4 from has_send_request to friends. In this case I can do a normal UPDATE query. However If I want to UPDATE the status from the users 2-4 I need to make one INSERT query and not one UPDATE query.

Comment: Please include sample data and then what should happen with insert condition.

Comment: I have added some sample data.

Comment: From the sample data it looks like the combination (`User_ID1, User_ID2`) should be unique.

Comment: Yes the combination is always unique, user 1 can only have 1 status with user 2.

Comment: So you can define a composite UNIQUE INDEX on those two fields, and your statement should work.

Comment: This may sound stupid but how? xD I am quite new to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: BTW: Instead of binding the `Status` twice you can also use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status = VALUES(Status)`.

Comment: I still don't really understand how to make one unique from from both users ID inside de INSERT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see attached image on how to create a unique key.

[image]