# Unique value if where id =?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a column in Database Unique but can duplicate if change another column number.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               Name                |    Status  | 
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               XerK                |     1      |    
|               cdya                |     1      |    
|               XerK                |     2      |
|               cdya                |     2      |   
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

I need to like this table but no duplicate when status same equal.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a unique composite like this

```
ALTER TABLE `yoourtable` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`Name`, `Status`);
```

Taken from [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Every time you "take" an old SO answer/solution and paste it into a new question a kitten dies.  Please do the right thing which is to delete your answer and flag/vote this question as a duplicate.