# mysql insert update if not exist with not unique index

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have seen some questions with a similar title but they do not answer my question**

I have one table like this

```
id  original    from_lang   translated  to_lang  ranking
 1   word1          es        trans1      en       0
 2   word1          es        trans2      en       1
 ...
```

`id` column is a `UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTOINCREMENT`

**The rest of the columns can not be unique**

**What I try to do:**  When I insert a new row, if the `original` column and `from_lang` column and `ranking` column are the same then update existing row but if not the same then insert a new entry row

I have tried this

```
INSERT INTO words
    (original, from_lang, translated, to_lang, ranking)
VALUES
    ('word1','es','trans3','en',0)

-- ... here is mi problem because I don't know how to use 
-- ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in my case that I have not UNIQUE columns
```

But the above query insert a new row

Espected:
`Update first row where id = 1`

Comment: Don't you mean if original, from_lang, to_lang and ranking are the same ?

Comment: Is this directly in MySQL or are you using something like PHP to create the query?

Comment: @PaulJanssens Yes you have reason my fault I will edit

Comment: You'll get answers that will be bad and will only appear to be working. The solution is to have a unique index. There's no reason why you can't have one. Your problem is figuring out how to place the unique index, not how to avoid it.

Comment: @MTK take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: @Rockhopper I can use PHP to create query .. also a stored procedure but I try to avoid to many query to  check

Comment: @N.B. You have also reason `Your problem is figuring out how to place the unique index, not how to avoid it` ... So how to place a unique index to acheive that ?

Comment: You have already answered that yourself, create a unique index containing original, from_lang and ranking

Comment: @PeterM ... It seem that is what I need (I have checked your link)

Comment: Add a new field, call it `unique_id`. Make it `BINARY(32)`. Store the hash of `original  + from_lang` into that field. You can create a trigger that does that for you. Problem solved, your unique index will always be of fixed length and your `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will work.

Comment: @N.B. Ok thanks. I did not know that. your suggestion  Peter M suggestion and Joakim Danielson suggestion seem to be the right solution for me

Comment: @N.B. `index will always be of fixed length` ... That made your suggestion to be the better (in mi case ) because I want to expand this to phrases also