# avoid duplicate entry INSERT SQL

Tags: php, sql

Im inserting the daily attendance. I want to avoid duplicate entries. The unique columns should be the month, day and ID altogether.
My condition is "if month and day exist for that employee ID,(For example, if there's already an attendance for March 22 for employee#40) it should return an error and should not proceed to inserting.  This is my code.

```
    $avoid_double_entry = query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE 
    employee_id = '$employee_id' AND month = '$month' AND day = '$day' ");
    confirm($avoid_double_entry);

    if($row = fetch_array($avoid_double_entry)) {
            echo "already exists";
    } else {
        echo "no records found";
     <--proceed to insert query-->
```

However, when I run this code, and when there's an entry for DAY 22, even the month is not March and the employee ID is not 40, it says already exists. It also happens when the day is not 22 but the month is March, vice versa.

It only says no records found when the three conditions are not met. I kind of understand this part. What I don't understand is why it says already exists even only one condition is met. Thanks in advance for your help.

I already tried not query WHERE NOT, DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but still cant figure it out..

By the way, this is my confirm function which is working fine, but just in case.

```
 function confirm($result) {

global $connection;

if(!$result) {

    die("Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection)); 
}
```

}

Comment: use `num_rows` instead

Comment: can you edit your question and put the table structure in?

Comment: Make id, month, day a key on your table, no need for any PHP here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute a `SELECT` query before executing an `INSERT` query to prevent duplicate entries.

You need to [create a unique index over the multiple columns that must be unique in your table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Then, execute your `INSERT` query. Duplicates will not be inserted. If you have other columns that should be updated if duplicates are encountered, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Otherwise `INSERT IGNORE` will prevent you from getting any errors when you try to insert duplicates (while still not inserting them).

Also, I would highly recommend storing your dates in a single date type column rather than storing the separate date parts in different columns.

Comment: I guess Tim lost his keys again.

Comment: Maybe Tim thought that what you posted was plagiarizing on an existing Q&A? Btw, my name's not Tim ;-)

Comment: Plagiarizing? Really, @Funk? Is there a certain one you're thinking of?

Comment: I don't know, I can't speak for the guy (or gal). Kind of seems like it to me in a way.

Comment: @Funk Well, I hope not. Plagiarism is a serious accusation. I'm not one to get my feelings hurt over a random downvote, but if someone really thinks I've plagiarized something, I'd like to know more about it so I can address it. If my answer resembles another, it's purely coincidental. Hopefully it doesn't resemble something else enough for someone to have that doubt.

Comment: Oh I never said *you* plagiarized. Coincidences can and do happen, no doubt about that.