# Is there a way to limit the number of entries in a table based on a number in another table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am new to mySql and phpmyadmin, I have two tables: the `college_building` table; this table has the following attributes: `id`, `name`, `number_of_classes`. Then the second table is the classes table; this table has `id` (auto-incremented) and `room_number` as attributes, and also the building id as a foreign key.

Is there a way to set a limit for the number of entries in the second table using the auto-incremented id based on the `number_of_classes`?

For example, if i have a building that has 20 class rooms, I want the classes table to have a maximum of 20 rows.

Comment: Usually this type of constraint is solved by a unique key constraint that only ever allows one class in one room at a give time to avoid overbooking rooms.

Comment: thank you for your reply :) I'm sorry but could u specify to where should I add this constraint?

Comment: [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635937/205233) should have the answer for that. The interesting problem in your case could be to avoid overlapping but still unique bookings. If you only allow a class for a whole day (or even a whole term) it should be simple enough.