# Mongo unique compound text index

Tags: mongodb, unique-index

I'm trying to create a Mongo index with 2 text fields, whereby either field can have a value in another document, but the same pair cannot. I am familiar with [this concept in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql), but do not understand it in Mongo.

I would like to create a unique index on the `symbol` and `date` fields of these documents:

```
db.earnings_quotes.insert({"symbol":"UNF","date":"2017-01-04","quote":{"price": 5000}});

db.earnings_quotes.createIndex({symbol: 'text', date: 'text'}, {unique: true})

db.earnings_quotes.insert({symbol: 'HAL', date: '2018-01-22', quote: { "price": 10000 }});
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 11000,
                "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: sample.earnings_quotes.$symbol_text_date_text  dup key: { : \"01\", : 0.6666666666666666 }"
        }
})
```

I don't understand the error message here... In this case, neither `symbol`, nor `date` overlap with the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `text index` actually behaves a bit like a `multikey index`, it tries to cut text into bits that can be then queried using specific text search operators. Also, the order of the fields in the `text` index doesn't really matter (compared to a normal compound index), MongoDB will just go through all the values in both `symbol` and `date` and index those separately.

In this case I believe that mongo tries to index the `01` in the `2017` and the `01` in `-01-` separately.

I don't think in your case you really want to do a text index, it's made for searching through long texts, not fields with single values in them.

And also, the multikey nature of the `text` index makes it really hard to stay unique.

My advice would be to go like this:
`db.earnings_quotes.createIndex({symbol: 1, date: 1}, {unique: true})`

Comment: Ok thanks. Making these changes, and doing some test inserts, it seems to be behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

By default mongo uses `_id` as unique key and index, so one solution to your problem is save your data in _id field.

e.g:

```
{
    "_id":{
            "symbol" :"xyz" ,
            "date" :"12-12-20" ,
        }

        //Other fields in collection
}
```

This will create a composite key.