# Insertion with unique constraint and condition (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

First I'll show you my interface so that you understand better:

[Add place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml3DQ.png)

So here is my problem I want the column "numero_place" is unique but with one condition, I explain that we have the local "parking wifaq" and we want to add a place if for example it already has a place that has the number 1 in this case I can not add another place that has the number 1 (which means that the column must be unique) but I want this unique constraint has a condition for example if I choose another local different from "parking_wifaq" for example we take the local that bears the name "parking ocean" in this case the parking when adding a place this place can have the number 1 even if the number 1 exists already in the local nomet "parking wifaq" I hope you understand me.

The problem is that I really do not know how to level the request the only thing I have done so far is to make the column "numero_place" unique but I have a problem because if I for example a place of a local that bears the number 1 I can not assigned to another local a place that bears the number 1.

I hope I was clear and you understood me I look forward to your response, and thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need a *composite* unique key (unique key over a combination of multiple columns).

Comment: can you tell me how to do it please?

Comment: See: [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: ok i go see it now

Comment: it works thanks you very much  !! the solution : ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT MyContrainte UNIQUE (column1,column2)