# Concurrent requests transaction to prevent unwanted persistence

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I am trying to get my head around how to approach what initially seems a "simple" problem.

I have `UserAccounts` that can have MANY `Purcahse`s BUT business logic dictates can only have one `Purchase` in a `PurchaseState.IDLE` state (a field on the entity). A `purchase` is IDLE when first created.

I have a repo with a method to determine if the user has a purchase with the given states already existing:

```java
boolean existsByPurchaseStateInAndUserAccount_Id(List<PurchaseState> purchaseState, long userAccountId);
```

I noticed with a bit of testing and thinking I can create more than one purchase when two requests are passed in close proximity/at the same time (i.e. a concurrency issue and/or race condition).

This leads to the user account having two purchases with both having an IDLE state.

I have drawn up a quick diagram to show what I think is happening:
[image: TX]

Now, is there a way using @Transactional that would cause the second persistence/transaction to rollback?
I am unsure if simply wrapping the service method in `@Transcational(isolation=REPEATED_READ)`
would relieve the issue? I.e. is there a way SQL will handle this transactionally?

I can only guess this wouldn't actually help as the existsBy is not tracked by the SQL transaction and therefore wont rollback?

Is the only real solution to run a second `countBy` query at the end of the method to rollback the transaction if there is >1 entity fitting the condition? I still don't feel this is "perfect" and fully solve the race condition/TX issue...

[image: TX2]

So the service will see there are 2 entities being committed across the two transactions (not yet committed) but for T2 the service can throw a RuntimeException to trigger the rollback?

Sorry, I have been reading  bits about Transaction isolation but it seems to only be applicable to say if I am checking a field value/column of an entity rather than using logic based on say the return of a "count(*)" query...

Thank you for any enlightenment.

Comment: @Turing85 yeah this would be my ideal situation.
I have done further googling and found maybe I can add a constraint on multiple fields of an entity?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "clean" solution would be to create a dedicated table `user_order_pending` with two columns: `user_id` and `order_id` (preferably both with a foreign key constraint)  and set a unique constraint on the `user_id`. Then, in one transaction, insert both the order into `orders` and the corresponding entry in `users_order_pending`. If two concurrent transactions would try to insert new pending orders concurrently, only one transaction would succeed, the other one would rollback.

If this change is too complex, there is another `mysql`-specific solution involving a `GENERATED` column. We create a new column `is_pending`, that is a `BOOLEAN` and nullable. Then, we set the value of this column to `true` if and only if the `status` column is `pending`. Finally, we set a `UNIQUE` constraint on columns `user_id` and `is_pending`. A rough sketch would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    status SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    is_pending BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        CASE
            WHEN status = 0 THEN 1
        END
    ),
    CONSTRAINT unique_user_id_is_pending UNIQUE (user_id, is_pending)
);
```

In the example above, a `status` of `0` represents `pending`. Now let us test our solution. First, we insert a new row in our table:

```
INSERT INTO orders(user_id) VALUES(1);
```

and check the results:

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | status | is_pending |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      0 |          1 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far, so good. Let us try to add another order for this user:

```
INSERT INTO orders(user_id) VALUES(1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'orders.unique_user_id_is_pending'
```

This insert gets rightfully rejected, great! Now let us update the existing entry and give it another status:

```
UPDATE orders SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

And again check the result:

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | status | is_pending |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |       NULL |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The generated column has updated, neat! Now finally, let us insert a new entry for the user with `user_id 1`:

```
INSERT INTO orders(user_id) VALUES(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

And sure enough, we have a second order for our user in database:

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | status | is_pending |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |       NULL |
|  3 |       1 |      0 |          1 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Since the constraint is on `user_id` and `is_pending`, we can add new pending orders for, e.g., `user_id 2`:

```
INSERT INTO orders(user_id) VALUES(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | status | is_pending |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |       NULL |
|  3 |       1 |      0 |          1 |
|  4 |       2 |      0 |          1 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And finally: since the constraint ignores `NULL`-values, we can move the second order for `user_id 1` into a not-pending state:

```
UPDATE orders SET status=1 WHERE id = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | status | is_pending |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |       NULL |
|  3 |       1 |      1 |       NULL |
|  4 |       2 |      0 |          1 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it can be added to an existing database if the databse is in a legal state, i.e. if there at most one `pending` order per user. The new column and the constraint can be added to the table without breaking existing code (save for the fact that some processes may not be able to insert data in the scenario described above, which is the desired behaviour).

Comment: This is looking exactly how I'd want it to be.
Option 1 is tempting as it is the more "correct" way I feel. I will peruse that route first. It may mean some business logic isn't viable which may leave with with option 2.

Option 2 seems logical and maybe what I need. I didn't know I could have multiple constraints like that. I'll have to do some reading around and some testing ofc.
Thank you for the in depth answer.

I am nearly two large glasses of wine down at the moment so wont be touching this till monday ha.

Thanks :).

Comment: @Jcov don't stress, my post isn't going anywhere :)

Comment: after all that the business requirements have changed and I haven't implemented the above.
I believe it makes sense and is probably the best solution so I am accepting it just incase someone else comes along with a similar issue.