# How to use "Insert Ignore Into" Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables :

1. user_details
2. user_badges
3. badges

[image]

I have a query where I use "insert ignore into" command to insert the badge id from badges and user id from user_details into user_badge.

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$getlife="SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE username='$username'";
$getlifedb=mysqli_query($db, $getlife);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getlifedb)){
    if($row['fullife'] == '1'){
       $full="INSERT IGNORE INTO user_badge(user_id, badge_id) 
                SELECT u.user_id, b.badge_id 
                FROM user_details as u 
                    CROSS JOIN badges as b 
                WHERE u.user_id='$id' 
                AND b.badge_id='8'";
        mysqli_query($db, $full) or die(mysqli_error($db));
   }
}
```

Below is the picture of user_badge table:

[image]

But every time I execute the command, the insert ignore doesnt work, but instead it just insert a field again. Can someone help me fix this issue.

Comment: Please explain what you thought you were using IGNORE to achieve

Comment: If you know the values of `user_id` and `badge_id` **What is the point** of running a query to select them?? You could write a simple query inserting the values into `user_badges` :) _I dont see where `$id` is actually given a value, but I am assuming it exists or the query makes even less sense

Comment: @RiggsFolly with IGNORE , i thought i dont need to insert again the same field again in user_badge table, for example if the badge_id 8 is already present in the table , the next insert ignore should ignore the insert operation

Comment: So what are the rules for Users and Badges? How many badges can a user have?

Comment: there are 8 badges and the user can have a badge only once

Comment: @RiggsFolly  there are 8 badges and the user can have each badge only once

Comment: So make the unique key `(user_id,badge_id)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have edited the question and added the picture of the user_badge table, if you see it you will understand . If i add unique key to user_id or badge _id . Then it will not allow the same user_id to have another badge_id

Comment: Make the Unique Key BOTH COLUMNS See this [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635943/2310830) or look up [Composite Index](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly will it be possible to use update query instead of insert ignore into

Comment: Not unless the row is already there and you just want to amend (UPDATE) it

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u show me how to update the user_badge table with user_details and badges

Comment: `CREATE INDEX \`user_badge_idx\` ON \`user_badge\` (\`user_id\`,\`badge_id\`);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE` only works when a duplicating field in table is being set as `UNIQUE`. `user_id` in table `user_badge` is not set to `UNIQUE`, that's why it duplicates it.

If you need to have multiple badges for an user, but those are not supposed to be duplicated, you need to set the pair to be `UNIQUE`, -> `UNIQUE(user_id,user_badge)`

Without `UNIQUE`, `INSERT IGNORE` doesn't make any sense, as it doesn't throw any errors when inserting the same records.

Comment: but if i set the user _id has unique, then the same user_id will not be able to get other badges from badge id

Comment: yes ok, so you need to set `UNIQUE(user_id,user_badge)`, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

From msql documentation "Use the INSERT IGNORE command rather than the INSERT command. If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record, then MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a duplicate, then the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error."
I agree fully with @Flush Thunder. If you do not care having duplicate entries just use INSERT instead, but for what you´re writing this is not the case.
Apparently, your user must have a unique id, while may have several badges which is consistent with a unique user.

Comment: if i make the user_id unique then the same user_id cant have another badge _id

Comment: Yes Uviii, you may have has many badges and badge_ids as you want. For the info you provided it seems you're dealing with a one-to_many relationship where a user may have several badges ( and each badge it´s supposed to have an id). Otherwise, you may set up a one to one relationship where a user may have one and only one badge.

Comment: If this were the case (one - to one) your user_badge table is redundant. You may deleted and and place the pertinent fields in your user_details table.