# Is there a way to prevent duplicate entries in an SQL DB that involves multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table of addresses, each address is set up so that it is split into its component parts, such as:

```
Address ID(PK, AI) 
Customer ID
Street Number
Street Name
City
etc.
```

I am wondering what the best way would be to add data so as not to have a duplicate combination of these values?

MY customers may have multiple addresses, but I want each combination to be unique.

Is there some way to throw an error when an entire row equals another row?

Thanks

Comment: See in the manual about UNIQUE indexes

Comment: you could create a unique index over all your columns, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score -1):

This is a many to many relation:

One way is to split into 3 tables:

```
Customers:{
    Customer ID (PK)
}

Address:{
   Address ID(PK)
   Street Number
   Street Name
   City
}

CustomerAddress{
    CustomerID (FK)
    AddressID (FK)

    (AddressId, CustomerID) = PK
}
```

`(AddressId, CustomerID) = PK` will ensure that the combination of (customer <-> address) is unique