# Mysql No duplicate Two column value in single resultset

Tags: mysql

I have table which have `createdby` and `publishedby` columns.

These two get the same value(userId) some time.

Need a correct mysql query to get user ids without duplicating from two column.

like createdby column = 102,103,104

publisheby column = 103,105,104

excepted result - 102,103,104,105

Comment: What types are these columns? Are the values really comma-delimited strings?

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Can you show us the code that insert's/updates these columns. Surely it can only be an error in the writing of the queries

Comment: The values are not comma-delimited strings. I'm just giving example. the column type bigint. I didn't give hear real datas. @Mureinik

Comment: Is it possible to get two columns values in single resultset without duplicate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `union` set operator to get results from both columns and remove duplicates:

```sql
SELECT createdby 
FROM   mytable
UNION
SELECT publisheby
FROM   mytable
```