# MySQL multiple checks and insert if atleast one is not duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, unique-constraint

I have a table where none of the columns are a key (Because all can be duplicate)

I want to insert var, var2, var3, var4, var5 into columns id, id2, id3, id4, id5 where there is **atleast** one non-duplicate present.

i.e if all are duplicate except id3, make a new entry but if all are duplicate don't insert.

Comment: Do you mean that every combination of (id, id2, id3, id4, id5) together has to be unique? Would a [multi-column UNIQUE constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/) do what you want?

Comment: what i mean is, if in id, id2, id3, id4, id5. atleast one is not duplicate make a new entry.
but if all of them is duplicate don't make an identical entry. not sure if that is what you mentioned. if so yes.

Comment: If the columns are all defined as NOT NULL, then the multi-column unique constraint mentioned by @WanderNauta would do that. If any of the columns allows NULLs, it probably won't work the way you want it to.

Comment: I've one column that allows NULLs. so is there no way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

No problems, create unique composite index. For nullable column use COALESCE and replace NULL with some char/string which cannot present in the value. For a delimiter use the char/string which cannot be a prefix/postfix for any value.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    f1 INT NOT NULL,
    f2 INT NOT NULL,
    f3 INT NOT NULL,
    f4 INT NOT NULL,
    f5 INT NULL,       -- nullable column
    UNIQUE ( (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(0), f1,f2,f3,f4,COALESCE(f5, CHAR(0)))) )
);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4229cd4fe3f0d2537e205c7c752554a2). `CHAR(0)` is used for both delimiter and NULL replacement.